# Javascript - CSV file from server and getting the result of the file and store in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, file-upload

I have a function that reads csv file :

```
  function load_data(csv) {

   var rows = d3.csv.parseRows(csv);
   create_table(rows);

 }
```

In the function above the result that goes into the **csv** argument looks like this:

```
 album,artist,price
 "lateralus","tool",13.00
 "aenima","tool",12.00
 "10,000 days","tool",14.00
 "down in it","nine inch nails",3.00
 "broken","nine inch nails",6.00
```

My question :

How can I hard-code a variable that stores a csv file path from my server and another variable that stores the content of the csv file as same as the above result? I will then pass the result into my function for further processing.

If I did this -

```
var filepath = "filepathontheserver/blabla/file.csv";
```

how do I open the csv file and put the content of the file in a var?

I know how to do it if the user were to upload it but that's out of the question because that option wont be available-

```
 var reader = new FileReader();

 reader.onload = function(e) {
 var contents = e.target.result;
 load_data(contents);
};
```

Comment: wait wait, are you using d3.js?

Comment: Yeap I'm using d3 but I want to make a variable that stores the path of the csv file because it wont change. but I don't know how to open the file and store the content of the file.( I know how to do it there's an option if the user can choose file.)

Comment: read d3.csv(file, function(data) { }) might work, if you are able to write file locally

Comment: Javascript is executed on the clients machine so your script would look for "/home/cpanel-username/public_html/file.csv" on the clients machine which would obviously not exist.

Comment: I don't want the client to upload anything. I just want to hardcode a path from the server and show it to user the result in the end

Comment: Javascript won't be able to access servside files!

Comment: If you are / can use PHP, then you can make you JS file a server parsed one, like "getCsvData.js.php", where you echo the data you want into the JS variable, like: <?php echo 'var file = "' . $csvFilePath . '";'; ?>. $csvFilePath would contain the string "filepathblabla/file.csv" for example.

Comment: I just want to read the file and its contents. - var filePath ="pathToMYCSVFile"; - if I have a folder that holds all my csv file in the same directory as my html can't I just hardcode - var filePath ="files/myCSV.csv" ? My main question is how to put open the file and put the content of the myCSV.csv in a var? (if it was FileReader then I know but that's when the user has an option to upload...which will be something like -   reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result; };  )

Comment: No You can not simply acces files that lie on your server from JavaScript. JavaScript is executed on the client therefore has not access to server side files. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp only your server side script would return the content of you csv file ionstead of database results.